# Error: BiocInstaller:::BIOC_VERSION == "3.1" is not TRUE

Tags: r, docker, bioconductor, rstudio-server

I am using Rserver (R version 3.2.1) with `docker run -p 8787:8787 bioconductor/devel_base`. However, I got the following error:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/workflows.R")
Bioconductor version 3.2 (BiocInstaller 1.19.9), ?biocLite for help
Error: BiocInstaller:::BIOC_VERSION == "3.1" is not TRUE
> workflowInstall("chipseqDB")
Error: could not find function "workflowInstall"
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need to have Bioconductor version `3.1` to be installed, and not the devel version `3.2`. And on the [dedicated page](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/rnaseqGene/), it is written that it has been "Built with Bioconductor (R): 3.1 (3.2.1)".

Comment: How is it possible to do?

Comment: https://bioconductor.org/developers/useDevel/. You also can use your favorite WSE (web search engine) to find answers.

Comment: You are using Bioconductor 3.2 (devel) here; you need to be using 3.1 (release). You can use release by doing `library(BiocInstaller);useDevel(FALSE)`` or set up a separate R installation for release, then the command should work.